# how to solve Cannot instantiate the type Workbook in java?

Tags: java, vba, excel, jxl

Hi i want to copy a excel sheet from one folder to other folder but a error is being occured regularly `Cannot instantiate the type Workbook` i am not able to understanding this syntax error please see my code in below -

```
 package com.esurfer.db;

 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

 import com.esurfer.db.DBConn;
 import com.esurfer.db.GetExcelNo;

 import jxl.Cell;
 import jxl.CellType;
 import jxl.DateCell;
 import jxl.Sheet;
 import jxl.Workbook;
 import jxl.*;

 public class DemoFile {

// import data from excel to mysql
public boolean importdata() {

    //Create a new Workbook by excel file path
    Workbook wb = new Workbook("d:\\test\\book1.xls");

    //Create a Worksheets object with reference to
    //the sheets of the Workbook.
    WorksheetCollection sheets = wb.getWorksheets();

    //Copy data to a new sheet from an existing
    //sheet within the Workbook.
    sheets.addCopy("MySheet");

    //Save the excel file.
    wb.save("d:\\test\\mybook.xls");

    return true;
 }

private static java.sql.Timestamp getCurrentTimeStamp() {

    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    return new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime());

}
}
```

Please suggest me solve this syntax error
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Workbook` is an abstract class, so you cannot create an instance of it.
What you can do is using its static factory method:

```
Workbook sourceWb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("d:\\test\\book1.xls"));
```

You can learn more at this [tutorial](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html) or the [API](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html).

Take a look at [`getWorkbook()`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html#getWorkbook%28java.io.File%29) and [`createWorkbook()`](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html#createWorkbook%28java.io.File,%20jxl.Workbook%29)

Comment: you sure its interface. how come the method is accessed with interface  name.

Comment: I am not sure, but shouldn't he use `getWorkbook` instead of `createWorkbook`? Because I think he wants to open an existing file

Answer (score 1):

`Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("d:\\test\\book1.xls"));`

You should read how it's done before doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("d:\\test\\book1.xls"));
```

To create an Workbook. You cannot instantiate the class.